# Accelerometer code

Tags: android

I am working with accelerometer for android, I do not understand why the three axis for them which I have assigned to mSensorX, mSensorY and mSensorZ are labelled as unused when I have used them in the onSensorChange, could someone please help me understand this.

```
package com.example.imageaccel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ImageAccelActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView x, y, z;
    private float mSensorX;
    private float mSensorY;
    private float mSensorZ;
    private Bitmap car;


    private SensorManager sm = null;
//  Bitmap car1;
//  float x1, y1, z1, sensorX, sensorY, sensorZ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    x = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
    y = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
    z = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);

    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() !=0){
        Sensor s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }

}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        sm.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent ev) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(ev.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

            mSensorX = ev.values[0];
            mSensorY = ev.values[1];
            mSensorZ = ev.values[2];


        }

}
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                /*
                 * draw the background
                 */

                canvas.drawBitmap(car, 0, 0, null);

    }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're *setting* them to a value but that's only half the story. The complaint is most likely that you're never *using* them after that. It's similar to the C code:

```
int main (void) {
    int a = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

While that compiles and runs fine, you do get a warning (using `gcc -Wall`) that:

```
warning: unused variable 'a'
```

Quick way to check this theory, put a:

```
System.out.println (mSensorX + "," + mSensorY + "," + mSensorZ);
```

(or some other sort of use) following the setting and see if the warning disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a warning because of the if statement there..In some cases they won't be used and hence the warning..That's my opinion:)